# Ember.js - is it possible to store/restore Ember.TEMPLATES in window.localStorage?

Tags: ember.js, local-storage, handlebars.js

I wonder if it's possible to store/restore the `Ember.TEMPLATES` cache object in the `localStorage` of the client?

The reason why I want to do this is because I'm not sending the client the whole bunch of precompiled templates at first, but loading them 'on demand' from the backend server. Now, if the user decides to reload the browser, I want to save/restore the whole `Ember.TEMPLATES` object so that the client doesn't need to query the backend server again for already requested template files.

I'm able to store the templates in the `localStorage` with the following function, but I guess it's not pretty (or performance optimized) at all:

```
saveCacheToLocalStorage: function() {
  var stringifiedCache = "{ ";

  for(var tmpl in Ember.TEMPLATES) {
    stringifiedCache += JSON.stringify({name: tmpl, template: Ember.TEMPLATES[tmpl].toString()});
  }

  stringifiedCache += " }";

  localStorage.setItem(this.localStorageId, stringifiedCache);

  this.hasChanged = false;

  return true;
}
```

but if I try to parse the stringified value from the `localStorage` it fails because of an `Syntax Error: Unexpected token: {`. Is there a better solution for my problem?

I am not able to deliver all precompiled templates at first, because the users of the web application access different areas and use different functions of the web app so it is not acceptable to serve the full set of templates to each and every user.

## EDIT

There were some errors in my scripts and now I'm able to store/restore templates in the `localStorage`, but I had to create another cache which temporarily stores the templates I fetch from the web server so that I am able to save them to the `localStorage`. Somehow I'm not able to get the templates from `Ember.TEMPLATES` itself, as I'm always getting the same function in return which is pretty useless (some general stuff for deprecation warnings, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, even when the syntax is correct, it still will not work because the template functions is generated and contains closure (scoped) information.

Your best bet is to precompile all the templates to a single `templates.js` and use (abuse) `localStorage` to cache the whole template script. (Manually, or with http://addyosmani.github.io/basket.js/)

Please note that `localStorage` is synchronous so it will block and might hang the browser for big template script.

Comment: thanks, but as I stated I am not able / do not want to deliver _all_ templates at once as it would pull down the initial loading time in a massive way...

Comment: My bad, you can always compile individual templates into js and cache them separately. What I mean is you have to cache the whole script file, not just the generated function.

Comment: ah, I see - so perhaps I'll work something out so that I can load template _bundles_ for different modules/routes, etc. - I really like this idea, thanks a lot!

Comment: I will accept your answer as I think I got the best ideas from our little discussion and close this topic. if you're interested to follow this topic along, chime in to the ongoing discussion over at http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/possibility-to-store-restore-ember-templates-at-window-localstorage/1536

Answer (score 0):

If you must do this, don't cache the compiled templates (they're functions and can't be stored in localStorage).  You can cache the templates themselves, and rebuild the compiled templates as you read them out of localStorage.  (Remember to expire the template yourself when you need to.  localStorage doesn't expire on its own.)

Comment: I have already flattened the precompiled templates and store a `String` within the `localStorage` - are there any security concerns about this? if I store the already precompiled templates I'm also able to rely on the smaller `Handlebars.runtime` library, instead of the bigger `Handlebars` library itselft which helps to minimize the size of the delivered scripts.

Comment: If it works without needing references to closured variables, that's pretty cool.  My concern was the same concern in tungd's answer, but I see you got around it.  :)